# How to find function and HTML code in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Normal when i try to customise WP style i would use inspector view in Chrome and this would allow me to locate style code easily.

i was wondering how i can do the same for HTML or PHP code in WP such as plugins and the CMS it self?

Thank you

Comment: HTML, CSS and JS can be seen in the Front end via code inspector. Code such as PHP is server-side and is only accessable server-side.

Comment: @user1789378 Do you want the edit the pages? If so, go to `/wp-admin` and then depending on your configuration, you can either edit 'sections' or go to 'Appearance' then 'Editor' which will give you a list of the .php* .html* files

Comment: Some plugin are wrap in <li> but i want each li to look different such as the shopping cart. So i want to easily change the class of that HTML tag by modifying it. The problem is that nearly most of all <li> uses the same class. i want to switch class for some of them

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side code and can't be found in the browser. If you want to see the code for WP plugins then you'll need to either download the plugin to your local machine or view the files on the server hosting WP.

Comment: I understand that, what i mean is that... on VS you can select a function and view them and it will go straight to the page where the function is located. Can you also do the same by locating a function or a tag in Dreamweaver?

Comment: I don't believe it works like that but i'll gladly be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Iassume you run it on your own root-/ webserver,...

so if you want to add HTML Elements to a post or site just do it in the text few like you would in an HTML-Editor like `<a href="target">for some link thing</a>` for instance (you should allready know that..'pretty shure it also works for js).

However if you want to customize the way every page on your blog looks, you can also do this manually, but it won't be as easy.
There should be a section under the theme customization part where you could upload your own css and php (at least with a lot of styles it's like that).

I WOULD NOT mess with the files on your server, if you don't know what you are doin, cause - to be honest - you can make a great blog/ website by using the tools it gives to you. ;)

I recommend using the stylesheet from your wordpress theme for a custom HTML-document based on the source of a blog page, if you go for the looks... and in every other case just use plugins! :P